# Configure Service Fabric to keep rolling logs of specific size

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to configure Service Fabric to keep rolling  fixed number of logs of specific size Y on disk.
For example, keep a maximum of 5 log files on disk with a file size not to exceed 5MB, file #1 is replaced when the last file meets the rollover criteria. 
I tried following links

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-reliabledictionarystateprovider-configuration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration
```

but I still can not find info I am looking for. I also tried following setting but with this, I can not specify number of files.

```
<Parameter Name="MaxDiskQuotaInMB" Value="10" />
<Parameter Name="DataDeletionAgeInDays" Value="3" />
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in version 5.4 (2.4 SDK), the local development clusters will use rolling file traces similar to what you described. The size of the log is fixed and a single file though.

This isn't supported in production clusters due to its performance impact.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Do we know when this feature will be available for dev cluster?

Comment: If you are using 2.4 SDK then you are already using it.  You can check by looking at 'logman query FabricTraces -ets'